# IBM Watson TTS adding non-speech sounds

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am using Watson TTS API. I would like to add a non-speech sound. I have looked through the documentation but cannot find anything. Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the text you'd be converting?

Comment: @tmarkiewicz a non-speech sounds such as a beep. For exmaple we are censoring a word and whenever that word should be rendered as speech it instead renders as a beep or any other sound.

Comment: Watson doesn't add non-speech sounds, however Google's TTS API allows it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Watson Text to Speech service you can create a custom model to handle transcribing these sounds. In the API, using the customizations endpoint, you can create a custom model and then populate it with word/translation pairs as needed.

The full documentation for creating and managing customizations can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/custom-using.html#cuWords